# Execute a script after a VPN connection is started

Tags: vpn, scripts

I'm starting a VPN connection using Network Manager.
Once the connection is established I have to change [MTU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) in order it to work properly.
For example:

```
sudo ifconfig ppp0 mtu 777
```

It is very annoying to execute this command every time I open a VPN connection. Is there any idea to create a script that would execute this command automatically once the connection is established (ppp0 interface is up)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d`, containing

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "ppp0" ]; then
    ifconfig ppp0 mtu 777
fi
```

and [make it executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122428/how-to-run-sh-file).

Comment: Two points: 1) the device name is probably "vpn0" these days, and 2) make sure that the filename of the script does not have a "." in it (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debianutils/+bug/38022)

Comment: This does not seem to work for ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04; I had to do this because `openconnect --mtu 1200` nor `--base-mtu 1200` had any effect with a Pulse Secure VPN.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a modernized (using `ip` instead of `ifconfig`) and generic (`openconnect` on the command-line uses `tun0`, Network Manager uses `vpn0` through the network applet; the numbers may vary if another network is already active) variant of @enzotib's excellent answer, tested on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$IFACE" =~ ^(tun|vpn)[0-9] ]]; then
    ip link set "$IFACE" mtu 777
fi
```

Comment: How about this way : `[[ "${IFACE%?}" =~ (tun|vpn) ]]`