# Execute script when [dis]connected to wifi?

Tags: wireless

I have two one-liner scripts that write IP address and SSID to files in my Dropbox; I would like my Android phone to sync to Dropbox and read the IP and SSID and do stuff via Tasker if it's on the same network.

That said, I am looking for a way to execute the scripts whenever I'm connected to wifi.

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execute a script after a VPN connection is started](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60784/execute-a-script-after-a-vpn-connection-is-started)

Comment: @enzotib - it's not *exactly* a duplicate, but that answer helped me out a lot. I'm still looking for a way to run a script pre-disconnect as well - basically I'm writing files to Dropbox based on the current network status of my laptop; before wireless shuts off I want to write to Dropbox and give it enough time to sync the changes to the cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add the following to my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

Then place a script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` and check if `"$IFACE" = "wlan0"`.

Comment: How did you figure it out? And what exactly does that script?