# How to run .sh file

Tags: files, executable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run .sh files in Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-files-in-terminal)

I want to download JDownloader from the internet for Linux. But the file is .sh and when I tell ubuntu to open the file it uses some text editor. I searched Ubuntu Software Store and there was no application  to open it. Is there any way I can get it installed?

Comment: simply drag the file inside the terminal and hit return key. installation will begin.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

1. copy the file to the desktop (for convenience)

   [image]
2. Right click on the file and select properties

   [image]
3. Under permission tab check allow executing file as program

   [image]
4. double click on the file and chose run in terminal if it is not a gui program)

   [image]

By default the file manager may not show that option and open the file in gedit instead. In that case change the preference of the file manager at: Edit-> Preferences -> Behaviour
to "ask each time" or right away to "run executables"

**Command line**

```
cd /path/to/file
chmod +x filename.sh
./filename.sh
```

Comment below if it wont work :)

If it still won't work, despite having allow executing file as a program ticked, when you double click on the .sh file, and it launches gedit, navigate to the folder with the script.

Once you are in the correct current folder for the script, you can run the script like this:

```
sudo ./filename.sh
```

If that doesn't work you may try

```
sudo bash filename.sh
```

**From FAT partition**

Follow this [How do I execute a file from a FAT USB drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23128/how-do-i-execute-a-file-from-a-fat-usb-drive)

Comment: Typically though, .sh files do need to be run in the terminal.

Comment: command line work but how can I run it with a double click? doesn't show the option "open with terminal"

Comment: @dodohjk, (in Ubuntu 13.04) there is an option that controls this - File > PReferences > Behavior > Executable Text Files

Comment: Just an FYI, I had to copy my file to another directory before this worked.

Comment: @Cody : To which directory??

Comment: I was following the command line instructions and trying to do this on a mounted USB drive. It failed to unpack until I copied it over to my desktop.

Comment: @Cody : That is because your USB drive is in either NTFS or FAT format . They do not support Linux permissions :-)

Comment: @Cody Read this too http://askubuntu.com/questions/23128/how-do-i-execute-a-file-from-a-fat-usb-drive

Comment: That's good to know. It was in FAT format, you're correct.

Comment: I am getting problem saying "Unable to locate the program". However, if I run program using `shell` it works fine.

Answer (score 58):

**Command line**

Apart from what *liquid* had recommended, usual procedure is to change permissions to make this file executable:

```
chmod +x file.sh
```

And then execute this file:

```
./file.sh
```

**GUI**

The same can be achieved in Nautilus file browser using context menu by changing `Execute` flags in `Properties` -> `Permissions`.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use `.` tricks, with the suggestion of other answers.

For example:

`chmod +x filename.sh`, assuming you have already gone to the path to file
then run the file with any one of these command:

```
sh filename.sh
./filename.sh
. filename.sh
```

Comment: The last one, `.` might not be what you want, since the variables and functions from the script will remain in your current shell.

Answer (score 9):

Try `sh nameoffile.sh` in terminal (making sure you are in the folder where `nameoffile.sh` is saved)