# How to install .run files?

Tags: installation, software-center

How can I install .run files?

When I open them with the software center, I always get the message that the file couldn't be opened.

Comment: You should really google before you post a question. See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/122428/how-to-run-sh-file

Comment: @TanelMae, damdimdum is new to Linux, he probably does not know that they could be run just like we run .sh files.

Comment: @Alaa, also new users are asked very nicely before posting a question to make sure that the question has been asked already. If people ignore that then it doesn't matter whether they are new to Ubuntu or not.

Comment: I am in no means saying that you shouldn't tell people to search before asking, I'm merely pointing out that you pointed the person to a question about `.sh` files, not `.run` files. Because when he sees your comment, it's likely that he'll go like "what? But I have a `.run` file". Point him to a question about `.run` would've made more sense.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I finally get it :)

Answer (score 2):

`.run` files usually are scripts. You should not install - execute any file - script outside of Ubuntu repositories, except if you trust 100% the source. 
You can see the contents of the `.run` file with an editor.

```
gedit <filename>.run
```

You can execute a `.run` file from terminal (CTRL+ALT+T). First give the appropriate permissions. You have to connect to folder where the file is. I assume is in Downloads folder

```
cd Downloads 
chmod +x <filename>.run
```

Then execute it with

```
./<filename>.run
```

or if needs root privileges (dangerous) , prefix with `sudo`