# How do I setup my HP C4140 printer wirelessly?

Tags: 13.04, command-line, printing

I found a tutorial on how to install my C4140 printer driver. However, I have run into a snag. [image: HPlip]

This is what the instructions say to do. I tried this, and this is what happens. [image: 13.04]

HPlip is installed, but I am doing something wrong.One of the things that I recently found is that I actually have hplip 3.13.3 and not version 3.13.9. So that may solve my issue if I knew how to upgrade hplip. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thank you in advance for all of your help.

Comment: I got 2 options which can or cannot be answers... 1. Is your hplip file located in the desktop? Probably is still in the Downloads folder tho. 2. Is your .run file executable? Most cases it should be executable tho, if it isn't, follow the isntructions from the answer in this http://askubuntu.com/questions/122428/how-to-run-sh-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade hplib run `sudo hp-upgrade`.

You can also use `sudo hp-setup` to install the drivers for a HP printer and to set it up -  this approach is easier when you need to install drivers for a HP printer again in the future.