# Can not run script file

Tags: scripts, .sh

i am new at ubuntu i installed COMODO antivirus and then to make it probaly working you have to run an script file, and i tried run a file an post_setup.sh from the teriminal by typing:

```
            gksu gedit post_setup.sh
```

making it executable does nothing as well, and the apps is called COMODO Antivirus, and  have a missing cmdavd.sh file can not find it by searcing the entire drev is this a bug, and it is installed probaly but is missing, and it is also installed from the softwarecenter.

Can someone please help.

Comment: Can you run the command `ls -alhs post.setup.sh` and add the output to your question?

Comment: He meant `post_setup.sh`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run .sh file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/122428/how-to-run-sh-file)

Answer (score 2):

To open the script file with gedit text viewer for example, use the following command:

```
gedit post.setup.sh
```

To execute the script, first give execute permissions to it:

```
chmod +x post.setup.sh
```

then you can execute it:

```
./post.setup.sh
```

If you are not the owner of that file and if you don't have permissions to read/write/execute that script, then run the above commands as root using `sudo` in front of them.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the file, choose properties, and once the new windows opens, go to the Permissions tab, and make sure that you have a check mark on Allow executing file as a program.  See images below.

[image]

[image]

Or you can use Radu Rădeanu answer to do it from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal (ctrl + alt + T) and run

```
chmod +x /location/of/your/file/post.setup.sh
```

Next run:

```
sh /location/of/your/file/post.setup.sh
```

You're done
If this didn't work just comment and I'll look into a solution.

Comment: If you run `sh /location/of/your/file/post.setup.sh`, `post.setup.sh` doesn't need to be executable, so `chmod +x /location/of/your/file/post.setup.sh` doesn't have sense.

Comment: It still writes sh: 0: Can't open /opt/comodo/post_setup.sh

Comment: try: `sudo chmod +r /opt/comodo/post_setup.sh` and then `sh /opt/comodo/post_setup.sh`

Comment: are you sure that is the correct file path?

Comment: Could you check if the file is actually there? type `cd /opt/comodo/` in the terminal followed by `ls -a` and check if you can find the file in the list

Comment: it writes/opt/COMODO$ sh post_setup.sh
-e Please run this script with administrator privileges.

Comment: add an sudo before your sh so: `sudo sh post_setup.sh`

Answer (score 0):

You can edit with gedit or vim/vi editor using one of the following commands

1. `gksu gedit post.setup.sh`  it will open in separate viewer.
2. `sudo vim post.setup.sh`