# How to Fix /home/braedon/Public/VideoE…/DaVinci_Resolve_14.1_Linux

Tags: scripts

I'm trying to install DaVinci Resolve. When I run

```
~$ sudo sh /home/braedon/Public/VideoE…/DaVinci_Resolve_14.1_Linux
```

To open the installer I get this error:

```
sh: 0: Can't open /home/braedon/Public/VideoE…/DaVinci_Resolve_14.1_Linux
```

I visited [Can not run script file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/387051/can-not-run-script-file) and tried the solution that they had suggested:

```
chmod +x /home/braedon/Public/VideoE…/DaVinci_Resolve_14.1_Linux
```

But that returned this error:

```
chmod: cannot access '/home/braedon/Public/VideoE…/DaVinci_Resolve_14.1_Linux': No such file or directory
```

I'm sure I've got the right directory because I copied the path from the file properties.
I'm stuck, can anyone offer a solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file properties dialogue didn't display the full path, that's why you see `VideoE…` in that path. As a workaround, try dragging the file into the terminal, the full path, quoted if necessary, will be pasted instead.