# Start application as root (No command line)

Tags: sudo, unity-dash, gui, appmenu, privileges

How can I start and application with root privileges, just once.

For example I need to start SublimeText with sudo privileges, then I write in a console:

```
$ sudo subl
```

But, I wonder if there's any way to do this from the dash or side bar.

Something similar to 'Launch as administrator' from Windows.

Comment: You **do not want** to start sublime as root!

Comment: @A.B. Sorry, do you mean that I shouldn't? It's an example, that could be nautilus or any other app.

Comment: use `gksudo` instead of `sudo`

Comment: @A.B. It's still a command line.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, one way is to [create executable shell script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122428/how-to-run-sh-file) and then using [pkexec](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/pkexec.1.html) run Sublime Text. I think that you can move the .sh file to dash then... But I am no longer using Ubuntu, so I am not so sure about this.

1. Create empty file: `touch run-sublime.sh`
2. Edit file using your favorite editor e.g. `subl run-sublime.sh`
3. Paste this in file

   > #!/bin/bash
   >      pkexec subl
4. Make script excutable: `chmod +x run-sublime.sh`

Answer (score 2):

You can [create](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) a .destop file with this:

```
Exec=pkexec subl
```

in the exec line and move this in the Dash.

and move that to the dash.

Comment: Better than my solution! :) Thanks for sharing!

Comment: How is a full .desktop file? And there's any way to make this and option on the normal app launcher?

Comment: You just have to put it in the right folder in your home where is the rest of .desktop files: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles#Adding_a_.desktop_file_to_the_Unity_Launcher